# Guard could not load class:rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I am learning rails testing. After hearing many different sources praising guard, I planned to install it to play with it. However, I am having problem installing it on my app.

I am following the steps shown at [guard rspec github](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec). Here is what I did:

```
gem 'guard-rspec', require: false #on gemfile development group

$ bundle install
$ bundle exec guard init rspec
```

I was able to `bundle install` with no difficulty, but whenever I ran `guard init rails rspec` it shows following error:

```
iggy$ guard init rails rspec
Expected string default value for '--listen-on'; got false (boolean)
22:19:09 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/rails' or find class Guard::Rails
22:19:09 - ERROR - Error is: cannot load such file -- guard/rails
22:19:09 - ERROR - /Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/guard-2.14.0/li...
...
/Users/iggy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/guard-2.14.0/lib/guard/dsl.rb:383:in `rescue in evaluate': Invalid Guardfile, original error is: 

Could not load class: "Rails", 
backtrace: 
    (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.14.0/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:57:in `initialize_plugin'
    (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.14.0/lib/guard/internals/plugins.rb:26:in `add'
...
```

I am not sure why it says it could not load `Rails` class. I ran `gem install rails`. Still exact same error.

Here is my full gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'carrierwave', '>= 1.0.0.rc', '< 2.0'
gem 'fog'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'devise'
gem 'searchkick'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.6.6'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.10.2'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5.3'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '4.6.0', require: false
end
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

The github for guard-rspec says:

```
Compatible with RSpec >2.99 & 3
Tested against Ruby 2.2.x, JRuby 9.0.5.0 and Rubinius.
```

I confirmed that my ruby is >= 2.2 and RSpec is v. 3+.

What do I need to fix to be able to run guard on my app? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`guard init rails` is unecessary. Because `guard init xxx` is only plugin names (`guard-xxx`).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what's wrong. I was playing with 2 different guards before: `guard-rails` and `guard-rspec`. Apparently I had ran `guard init` command while I had `guard-rails` in my gemfiles and it created a `Guardfile`.

When I changed `guard-rails` into `guard-rspec` and ran `guard init rspec`, it did not automatically overwrite the old `Guardfile`, causing the error. I deleted old `Guardfile`, had the correct guard: `guard-rspec` into my gemfiles, bundle installed, and ran `guard init rspec` and it worked!

Takeaways for me (and others):

If you ran into similar problem (having created guardfile but rails complaining that you don't have the right guard), note that `Guardfile`, once generated, won't be overwritten automatically. If you had different guard gem make sure to delete the old guardfile first and then create a new guardfile!